# What CMS to use to create a big city website

Tags: wordpress, drupal, content-management-system

I know there are so many similar questions, but none of them seems to answer what I am looking for. I have used WordPress but like 5 years ago, to create simple themes and websites. Since then I have been working on Web Applications such as React and Angular.

I am looking to bid on one of the city's website projects, but I need to understand what I am getting into. They ask to use a CMS. So my question is what CMS do they use when building big city websites?

https://www.edmonton.ca/

Notice the search functionality and `I want to` section they have. Popular search terms, popular programs/events/etc. Plus, they have categories within categories. I don't think it's feasible in WordPress. Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of government sites are using WordPress including the the-white-house, so I think that answers the question whether or not you can actually use WordPress for such project. All plafforms have their pros and cons, and for a project such as a government site, WordPress should be a completely viable solution.

// https://wordpress.org/showcase/the-white-house/

Regarding the search, there are a lot of free and paid search plugins that improves the default search functionality in WP, such as the Search and Filter and SearcWP plugin, but you could also rely on third party libraries and do your own implementations if there are no plugins that suits your taste.

Comment: The White House website is nowhere near as complex as edmonton.ca website. It has categories inside a category. Long-chain of categories.

Comment: WordPress supports taxonomy hierarchies, or terms within a parent term, child categories within parent category, whatever you want to call it. The only complex thing about the edmonton site is the search feature, which is actually not that complicated because it can be emulated with AJAX calls and might be possible using a single plugin such as https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-search-lite/.

Comment: The >> I want to << section is a list of drop downs that redirects to a certain page when selected.

Comment: hmm, that make sense! what do you prefer for a project like this. WordPress or Joomla or Drupal?

Comment: Plus I can write my own search functionality, as long as I can get all the posts/pages data through PHP. Which I am sure I have done it in the past.